# How to search all emails for a string in Outlook?

Tags: microsoft-outlook

In the newer unversioned Outlook how do I search all emails for a string? Say I want to find all emails with the string "hello.world" how could I find all emails including that string?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Open Outlook.

Use the Top Bar to start Search or use the Search tab if your Outlook is set up that way. I start with the Top Bar.

By default "Advanced Search" (only will see the words "Advanced Search" if you hover) button has the text "Current Folder" so click "Current Folder" to open "Advanced Search".

Select All Mailboxes.

Then enter the the string in the Body section and enclose in Quotes if the string includes spaces.

Then Search.

Here is a screen shot with all the options shown.

[image]